# JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance Implementation

Tags: javascript

Given the following case:

```
function Button() {
    this.a = "a";
}
Button.prototype = {
    aa: function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}

function AnimatedButton() {
    Button.call(this);
    this.b = "b";
}
```

Is there any reason (because it's a refence to the original prototype maybe?) not to add Button's prototypes to AnimatedButton via:

```
AnimatedButton.prototype = Button.prototype;
```

I've noticed that most places say that you should do this like:

```
AnimatedButton.prototype = Object.create(Button.prototype);
```

However, structurally, this makes the __ proto__'s nested.

Or alternatively, is there anything wrong with:

```
AnimatedButton.prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(Button.prototype));
```

with of course resetting the constructor via (after any of the 3 aforementioned cases):

```
AnimatedButton.prototype.constructor = AnimatedButton;
```

Comment: `Button.call(this);` is not a `new` instance.

Comment: The only problem, I believe, is if you overwrite the Constructor properties, with the prototype reassignment. If you make empty functions, then assign the prototype, then add your other properties, you should be fine.

Comment: If you say `AnimatedButton.prototype = Button.prototype;`, then anything you add later to `Button.prototype` will also be available on the `AnimatedButton` prototype, which is almost certainly not what you want.